# constraint a super class can not override the value of subclass

Tags: java

This method is in a Scores class, that is set the class variable scores, but the scores is combination of its sub class, for example, `scores = sub scores1 + sub scores2`, sub1/sub2 is calculated by the subclasses of Scores.

```
public void setScores (double scores) {
    this.scores = scores;
}

public void calculateScore(double sub1, double sub2) {
    this.scores = (sub1 + sub2) /2;
}
```

is there method/design skills/practice to constraint the class can't alter the scores value (i.e run the setScores), after the calculateScore() just ran.

Comment: I just can't understand your question. Give an example. You should make something private and/or final but I can't understand what you want to acheive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a flag `calculated` and if it is true, throw an exception in `setScores(...)`. Note that this approach only will enforce that constraint at runtime and you might miss a situation that throws the exception in your test.

Generally it would be favorable to enforce the constraint at compile time, but we'd need some more information. Here's an idea based on guesses on your other constraints:

You could also pass the scores to the constructor if you want `setScores(...)` to be called only once. In this case you either completely get rid of `setScores(...)` or make in protected to allow only this class, subclasses and classes in the same package to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of both methods, and implement `final double getScores(double sub1, double sub2)` to do the calculation, and return the required result.